# OutOfMemory exception on Exception.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling

Below is some logging output from a .NET application.

```
Error in MainFunction.
Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
InnerException: 
StackTrace:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Exception.GetStackTrace(Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Exception.ToString(Boolean needFileLineInfo)
   at System.Exception.ToString()
   [the rest of the trace is removed]
```

Which corresponds to the following line of application code.  The following is in a catch block, and returns the string to the method that actually throws:

```
private void MainFunction()
{
   ...

   try
   {
      string doc = CreateXMLDocument(); // <- Out of Memory throws here
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      CoreLogging("Error in MainFunction.", ex);
   }
}

private string CreateXMLDocument()
{
   try
   {
      //Some basic and well constrained XML document creation:
      ...
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return "Exception message: " + ex.ToString();  // <- This is the last line of the trace
   }
}
```

What should I make of this?  Clearly `Exception.Message` should be used instead of `Exception.ToString()`, but I'd still like to understand this.  Does

- at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
- at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)

mean that the stack trace of the exception in CreateXMLDocument was so mammoth caused OutOfMemory?  I'm curious to see how that would occur as there's definitely no circular calls in CreateXMLDocument, which is the only thing I can think of that could cause an enormous stack trace.

Has anyone else encountered a similar situation?

Comment: It's most likely a red herring. How are you loading the XML document?

Comment: Not pertinent to your question, but why are you _returning_ the exception instead of _throwing_ it back?

Comment: @asawyer The XML document is actually just a string that is constructed by iterating through a very small collection (and there are bounds contraints to ensure it cannot iterate over too large a collection).

Comment: Are you using recursion anywhere?

Comment: @DStanley Unfortunately, this was a requirement.  The XML doc eventually gets written to a TCP socket, where the listener simply bubbles up error text if the received item is not a valid XML doc.

Comment: Log all the necessary state to recreate the problem in the catch block of `CreateXmlDocument` to a file.  Your case is interesting as is but it would be better with something reproducible.

Comment: It also doesn't have to mean there's too much in the stack trace. Out of memory exceptions are caused when the *total* memory available is low; if you're using a lot of memory elsewhere and close to running out, even small unrelated things can cause it. However, I agree with @asawyer that it's probably something else causing it.

Comment: How big are the XML files?  Close to, much bigger than, or much less than, the amount of memory that you have?  Is this a 32 bit or 64 bit exe?

Comment: @Servy the documents never exceed a few hundred kilobytes.

Comment: @kmarks2 - So you client is prepared to handle either a valid XML document or an exception dump?  Seems odd.  Also the `CoreLogging` call will NEVER execute because `CreateXMLDocument` will swallow any exceptions.

Comment: @DStanley Well, it got to handle the OOM exception at least.

Comment: @DStanley The OutOfMemory is caught in MainFunction, and CoreLogging does execute -- the stacktrace I provided was rendered to a log file from MainFunction.

Comment: Can you please post a small reproducible example?

Comment: @kmarks2 - fair enough - it is caught because your catch block throws another exception, but the original exception is swallowed.  Still seems like a code smell.

Comment: @Asawyer The error has not occurred before and I can't reproduce it.  I think Ken must be right, it's a coincidence and the OOM is caused elsewhere.

Comment: 32 or 64 bits? Any object bigger than 85000 bytes will be allocated on LOH. If you are allocating and deallocating too many objects -  specially on 32bit env - you'll likely end up getting a OutOfMemoryException. Implement some object pooling algo could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I little bit of guessing:

1) CLR rises a OutOfMemoryException. 2) You catch this exception and call `.ToString` on it
3) `ToString()` tries to allocate memory to the stack trace but... there is no memory and another `OutOfMemoryException` is rised.

In the comments you said that the XML documents have a few hundreds of kbytes, this *could* be a/the problem if your server run on 32bits, because of the fragmentation of the LOH.